# docker-compose - Spring boot doesn't connect to postgres unless network_mode: host

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker-compose

Trying to run integration tests locally on Mac using docker-compose
The only way I can connect application to database is using network_mode: host.

It could be this way but I can't reach the application endpoint as in a Linux env by:  curl localhost:8080/blabla

I've tried all the Stack Overflow answers and many many configurations and different versions of docker-compose.yml but none worked so far.

Always the same problem unless network host.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    expose:
      - "8085"
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - mypostgres
    environment:
      - PROFILE=local
      - DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db
      - DB_USER=xxxx
      - DB_SECRET=xxxx
      - DB_PORT=5432


  mypostgres:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./db
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - $HOME/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxx
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxxx
      - POSTGRES_DB=xxxx


  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Comment: Have also searched the whole stackoverflow and hell a lot of other resources but only network_mode=host is working. I use Docker Desktop on Windows 10.